# Which architecture to use for HPC

Tags: windows-server-2008, soa, windows-server-2008-r2, hpc

So I have been looking into writing a dispatcher for our software to integrate with Windows HPC server 2008 . The stuff we want to integrate is Embarrisingly parallel with no data shared between tasks.

I have read about Microsofts SOA architecture, and see it as a very strong possibility. But I cant find anything about what other architectures you can use to create and run jobs on the cluster.

I know that there is MPI but I think that this is more aimed at jobs where tasks need to share data and inform each other of progress etc.

So my question is Other than SOA and MPI what other options are there?

Also I have heard some rumours that there are flaws in the SOA architecture can anyone relay information on how it is to work with?

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://resourcekit.windowshpc.net/ and searched for SOA? You might find other useful stuff too in this Windows HPC resource kit done by my team.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the overall architecture of you system is intending to do but there are a couple of different flavors of MPI on the market.  I am most familiar with Intel MPI.  Intel has a cluster tool suite that has MPI, compilers (C++ and fortran) and diagnotic tools in it.

Some of the threading runtimes are open sourced if those are needed at

www.threadingbuildingblocks.org

www.cilkplus.org